# generate Uniqe value

Tags: vba, excel

I try to write a code that generates three types of serials.

If var1 is comp1 serial must start with “AG” and it must look like AG160001.
If var1 is comp2 serial must start with “IG” and it must look like IG160001.
If var1 is comp3 serial must start with “GC” and it must look like GC160001.
Every time I push button “generate serial” it searches value of var1 and if its comp1 then it generates serial AG160002.

The code works great. But when I run another code, I get error on running this code.
Error is on line:
Object variable not set (Error 91)
varN = Range("A:A").Find("GC", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

```
Sub IDgen()

 Dim LastId As String
 Dim NewId As String
 Dim var1 As String
 Dim varN As Long
 Dim wsLVZKpk As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim wbLVZKpk As Excel.Workbook
 Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook
 Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
 Dim objListRows As ListRows

 Set awkb = ActiveWorkbook
 Set awks = awkb.Sheets(1)


 awks.Activate
 var1 = Range("perceel").Value
 If var1 = "" Then
 awks.Activate
 MsgBox "select comp"
 Exit Sub
 End If

 LVZKpk = "c:\test.xlsm"
 Set wbLVZKpk = Workbooks.Open(LVZKpk)
 Set wsLVZKpk = wbLVZKpk.Sheets(1)

 If var1 = "com1" Then
 wsLVZKpk.Activate

 varN = Range("A:A").Find("AG", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 LastId = Cells(varN, "A").Value
 NewId = "AG" & CLng(Mid(LastId, 3)) + 1
 awks.Activate
 Range("bestand").Value = NewId
 wbLVZKpk.Close

 ElseIf var1 = "comp2" Then
 wsLVZKpk.Activate
 varN = Range("A:A").Find("IG", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 LastId = Cells(varN, "A").Value
 NewId = "IG" & CLng(Mid(LastId, 3)) + 1
 awks.Activate
 Range("bestand").Value = NewId
 wbLVZKpk.Close


 ElseIf var1 = "com3" Then
 wsLVZKpk.Activate
 varN = Range("A:A").Find("GC", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
 LastId = Cells(varN, "A").Value
 NewId = "GC" & CLng(Mid(LastId, 3)) + 1
 awks.Activate
 Range("bestand").Value = NewId
 wbLVZKpk.Close

 End If


 Exit Sub

 End Sub
```

Comment: The error means that `.Find` isn't returning anything. Does the "other code" change the active sheet? I suspect you just need to fully qualify your `Range` and `Cell` references.

Comment: I changed 

     varN = Range("A:A").Find("AG", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

To 
      varN = wsLVZKpk.Range("A:A").Find("AG", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are receiving Error 91 because the value "AG" is not found in the specified Range.

Try replacing this:

```
varN = Range("A:A").Find("AG", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastId = Cells(varN, "A").Value
NewId = "AG" & CLng(Mid(LastId, 3)) + 1
awks.Activate
Range("bestand").Value = NewId
wbLVZKpk.Close
```

With something like this:

```
Dim rngFind As Excel.Range
Set rngFind = Range("A:A").Find("AG", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
If Not rngFind Is Nothing Then
  varN = rngFind.Row
  LastId = Cells(varN, "A").Value
  NewId = "AG" & CLng(Mid(LastId, 3)) + 1
  awks.Activate
  Range("bestand").Value = NewId
  wbLVZKpk.Close
End If
```

Also, it seems that:

1. Your `wkb` and `wks` variables should actually be Dimensioned as
   `awkb` and `awks`, respectively
2. A `Dim LVZKpk As String` line is
   missing

If you specify "Option Explicit" at the top of the module, you'll be alerted to issues such as these when you compile or run your code.